# Centos: getting this error on Atom editor

Tags: centos, atom-editor

Trying to run a simple java code in atom editor but giving the error: `bash javac command not found`.

Tried to set the path as follows but does not resolve the problem:

```
[root@localhost ~]# export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el7_4.x86_64 
[root@localhost ~]# export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

[image: Here is the screenshot of my centos terminal and in background, the atom editor showing error]

Answer (score 1):

Run this command `su -c 'yum provides javac'` 

This will tell you what packages will provide javac

Just because you installed a java RE doesn't mean you have a Java DK
Install `java-devel` or `java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel` or whatever version you want.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing just one line of command. Here it goes. sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel. And worked fine now.

Comment: @PalakGargAgarwal Mark it as 'best answer' so it is resolved.